# { "product": [ "This field is required."] } in Django REST API

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

This is my models and I defined set null=True, blank=True for foreign key relations but when I hit my API then API response raised that
{ "product": [ "This field is required."] }. What I wrote wrong. please help me.

**Here is my model:**

```
class CashSell(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey('accounts.UserProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey('inventory.Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cash_sell', null=True, blank=True)
    cash_sell_debit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date = models.DateField()
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='cash_sell_pics', blank=True, null=True, default='images.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_profile.first_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Cash Sell"
        verbose_name_plural = "Cash Sell"
```

[image]

**Here is my views:**

```
class CashSellViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CashSell.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReadCashSellSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ('list', 'retrieve'):
            return ReadCashSellSerializer
        return WriteCashSellSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Only show user related items."""
        return CashSell.objects.filter(user_profile__id=self.request.user.id)
```

And here is my Serializers:

```
class WriteCashSellSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='id', queryset=Product.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = CashSell
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: What REST API request are you sending to the server?

Comment: Did you run makemigrations and migrate? And could you show view at which you are making POST request and serializer?

Comment: Post request I've sent. And yes, I have, both makemigrations and migrate properly.

Comment: Are u using validators?

Comment: @Bairavan I've edited. Please check it out.

Comment: You haven't set allow_null on product in serializer

Comment: @TrueGopnik how to set please ?

Comment: product = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='id', queryset=Product.objects.all(), allow_null=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your serializer like this

```
class WriteCashSellSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='id', queryset=Product.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = CashSell
        fields = '__all__'
```

You are redefinining field in serializer so you need to add `required=False` flag.